# Why is my Apriori function returning letters instead of items?? (wrong output)

Tags: python, pandas, apriori

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from apyori import apriori

dataset = [['egg','bread'],['milk'],['apple','milk'],['diapers'],['orange','egg','milk']]
te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(dataset).transform(dataset)
final_df = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)
print(final_df)

frq_itemsets= apriori(final_df, min_support=0.5, use_colnames=True)  
association_results = list(frq_itemsets)
print(association_results)
```

The output:

```
apple  bread  china    egg  embroidery   milk
0  False   True  False   True       False  False
1  False  False  False  False       False   True
2   True  False  False  False       False   True
3  False  False  False  False        True  False
4  False  False   True   True       False   True
[RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'a'}), support=0.5, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'a'}), confidence=0.5, lift=1.0)]), RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'e'}), support=0.6666666666666666, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'e'}), confidence=0.6666666666666666, lift=1.0)]), RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'i'}), support=0.5, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'i'}), confidence=0.5, lift=1.0)])]
```

What am I doing wrong?? I've searched everywhere on SO but I cant seem to find a question like this.

Thanks in advance. I hope it's not a stupid question. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not familiar with both `mlxtend` or `apyori` but a quick look seems to indicate that first a `apriori` method exist in [`mlxtend` ](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/apriori/) so any reason to use another package? also second, the way you are using `apriori` from `apyori` looks more the way (parameters, dataframe passed) to use the function from the `mlxtend` package, in `apyori`, try to pass directly your `dataset` and not the transformed dataframe maybe?

Comment: Hi @Ben.T thanks for replying!! When i use `from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori` and print the results i get the output `['support', 'itemsets']`. Those seem to be the columns of the object apriori() returns. Thats pretty much why i tried to use apyori as I couldnt fix that issue.

Comment: If I feed the dataset directly into the apriori() I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'size'`

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a misuse of `apriori` depending on from which package you get it. See below the difference

```
import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder

dataset = [['egg','bread'],['milk'],['apple','milk'],
           ['diapers'],['orange','egg','milk']]
te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(dataset).transform(dataset)
final_df = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)
print(final_df)

from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
# this method returns a dataframe, no need to use a list
df_freq = apriori(final_df, min_support=0.5, use_colnames=True)  
print(df_freq) 
#    support itemsets
# 0      0.6   (milk)

from apyori import apriori
# this method returns a generator hence the use of list to get the result
print(list(apriori(dataset, min_support=0.5, )))
# [RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'milk'}), support=0.6, 
#                 ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), 
#                                     items_add=frozenset({'milk'}), 
#                                     confidence=0.6, lift=1.0)])]
```

Comment: Didn't get the difference between the packages in their output till now thanks!! However, I am still getting output as `OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'b'}), items_add=frozenset({'.', 'u'}), confidence=0.9511924998712203, lift=1.0), OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset({'u'}), items_add=frozenset({'.', 'b'}), confidence=1.0, lift=1.0),` in this form. I have a larger dataset that I am working on to get rules and this is my problem really

Comment: @cat1234 without the dataset, it is hard to tell why you get this result. that said to get this kind of result could be that your dataset is not a list of list of strings, but a simple list of strings. in your real case, what are `type(dataset)` and if list, then `type(dataset[0])` and if list then `type(dataset[0][0])`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem! For me, the solution was one-hot encoding the DF. In easiest terms, depending on your data set, this means converting it into a list.

```css
df = df.astype(str)
str_df = df.values.tolist()
te_ary = te.fit(str_list).transform(str_list)
```

That fixed it for me!